# Bold description text from Google Sheets script to Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script to create calendar events from a Google sheet.  It is working well, but I would like to bold certain text within the Calendar event description.  I can't seem to find a way to do this!  Any advice?

By the way, its just set up to read one line right now so that I can test it...

Here is my script:

```
'''
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Sync to Calendar', functionName: 'syncCalendar'},
   ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Sync to Calendar', menuItems);
}


function syncCalendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDAR ID");
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A32:U32").getValues();

    for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

    var shift = signups[x];

    var buildDate = shift[0];
    var steelPO = shift[1];
    var name = shift[2];
    var size = shift[3];
    var install = shift[4];
    var fabnotes = shift[5];
    var shopnotes = shift[8];
    var buildnotes = shift[10];
    var leadbuilder = shift[11];
    var contact = shift[12];
    var location = shift[13];
    var advanced = {location:location, description:("Steel PO " + steelPO + "\n\nLead Builder: " + leadbuilder + "\n\nContact: " + contact + "\n\nBuild Notes: " + buildnotes + "\n\nShop Notes: " + shopnotes + "\n\nFab Notes: " + fabnotes)};

  eventCal.createAllDayEvent((name + " " + size + " " + install), buildDate, advanced);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the value for the description of calendar event as the bold type.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- For the description of calendar event, HTML tag can be used.

  - When I had retrieved the event which has the description of the bold type and the hyperlinks, I could notice that the HTML tags are used. So I could know to be able to use HTML tags for the description. But I couldn't find the official document about this. So I'm not sure whether all HTML tags can be used. I apologize for this.

#### Modified script:

As a test case, when `steelPO` of `description` is set as the bold type, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var advanced = {location:location, description:("Steel PO " + steelPO + "\n\nLead Builder: " + leadbuilder + "\n\nContact: " + contact + "\n\nBuild Notes: " + buildnotes + "\n\nShop Notes: " + shopnotes + "\n\nFab Notes: " + fabnotes)};
```

To:

```
var advanced = {location:location, description:("Steel PO <b>" + steelPO + "</b>\n\nLead Builder: " + leadbuilder + "\n\nContact: " + contact + "\n\nBuild Notes: " + buildnotes + "\n\nShop Notes: " + shopnotes + "\n\nFab Notes: " + fabnotes)};
```

- HTML tag of `<b>` was added.

#### Reference:

- [createAllDayEvent(title, date, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createalldayeventtitle,-date,-options)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about your situation of `it doesn't`. Can you provide the flow for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sorry.  I went into a Personal Management Program I wrote and added the simple html and it seems to work.  So sorry to bother you.  I should have known better.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying and testing it. No problem. I hope that Google should reflect to be able to use HTML tags to the official document.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you!  When trying html before I had put the tags outside of the " marks.  Putting them inside is working now.  Thanks again...

Comment: @Tomm Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.